# MacOS - Vulkan at runtime vkCreateDevice() fails when VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures wideLines = VK_TURE and doestn’t support vkCmdSetLineWidth API as well

Tags: macos, metal, vulkan, image-rendering, moltenvk

I am new to Vulkan, and recently started learning .

I am facing issue, at runtime in `vkCreateDevice()` fails, when `VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures` is enables with

> VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures features {};
> features.wideLines                            = VK_TRUE;
> Error – [mvk-error] VK_ERROR_FEATURE_NOT_PRESENT: vkCmdSetLineWidth(): The current device does not support wide lines

And when features.wideLines = VK_FALSE; vkCreateDevice() creations is successful, but I am not able to modify the LineWidth using - vkCmdSetLineWidth (command_buffer, line_width); this gives me

> error- [mvk-error] VK_ERROR_FEATURE_NOT_PRESENT: vkCmdSetLineWidth(): The current device does not support wide lines.

here is some of details -

> MacOS - 10.14 (Mojave)
> Graphics card - Graphichs - Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB
> LunarG Vulkan Instance Version: 1.2.154
> Note- Same version of “LunarG Vulkan Instance Version: 1.2.154” on windows is working fine when features.wideLines = VK_TRUE; and able to use vkCmdSetLineWidth (command_buffer, line_width);
> Some of details of VulkanInfo mentioning here related to wideLines feature-

VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures:

```
geometryShader       = false
wideLines            = false
lineWidthRange: count =  2
        1
        1
lineWidthGranularity = 1
strictLines          = false
```

I did some searches in Vulkan Documentation/on google, but couldn’t find anyone reporting a similar issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you were [told elsewhere](https://community.khronos.org/t/macos-vulkan-at-runtime-vkcreatedevice-fails-when-vkphysicaldevicefeatures-widelines-vk-ture-and-doestnt-support-vkcmdsetlinewidth-api-as-well/106443), Metal does not support wide-lines, so MoltenVK (Vulkan over Metal) cannot support wide lines either. You will have to render wide lines manually with polygons.